# How to get connected two or more turtles within radius NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I have more turtles moving in the world, i would like to get them connected when they are inside an area (circles).

This is an example:

[image]

I was trying with a function like this, called in the "go" procedure (tick advanced) but this doesn't work.
Any suggestion?

```
to connect
ask turtles in-radius radius [
  create-link-from myself
  create-link-to myself
]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood what you want, this will work

```
globals [radius]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 50 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  set radius 5
  connect
end

to connect
  ask turtles
  [ ask other turtles in-radius radius
    [ create-link-from myself
    ]
  ]
end
```

The problem is that you have `ask turtles in-radius ...` but you don't specify the reference point. That is, within a certain distance of what? In my code, I ask each turtle to become the reference point and then ask the turtles within distance of itself to do the linking.

Comment: That's ok! And in a situation like that, how can i select the turtle that is going away (not myself, the other) to change its color? @JenB

Comment: please ask additional questions in separate posts so that (1) it is clear which posts are not yet answered and (2) people searching for an answer to their question can most effectively find already provided answers